# Popup message saying thankyou but file continues to download

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have links that download quite big files and sometimes they can take while before they start to download. I want to create a pop message in jQuery (so I can style it) that says thank you and then a sec latter the file downloads. I've tried using :

http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/

Code:

```
<script>
    ;(function($){
        $(function(){
            $('a').bind('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This displays the pop message but the file doesn't download. Does anyone else have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
 e.preventDefault();
```

…stops the default behaviour of the link (which is visiting the URL of the file you want to download). Don't do that.